# windows service cannot stop

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

Created a simple WCF service that basically logs to a db.
the build is fine and created a msi install file for it. 
I installed the windows service and start it which works, however when i stop it i get this error:

> "Could not stop the service1 service
>   on local computer. The service did not
>   return an error. This could be an
>   internal windows error or an internal
>   service error. If the problem
>   persists, contact your system
>   administrator."

Comment: can you post the code inside OnStop event of the service?

Comment: ok sure..please give me solution

Comment: As Stephan P. suggested, please post the OnClose code. Right now there is just nothing we can work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to diagnose this:

If you haven't already, separate out the implementation of the windows service from the actual service executable.  That way you can run / debug the code from a console or forms app easily.

If that doesn't reveal any answers, add verbose logging to the shutdown method to find out what is happening.

Comment: Services are hard to debug by themselves, but through a winform you get the exact error and the exact line. This is definitly a solution

Comment: @Mathieu: Services are as easy to debug as anything else. You just need to attach the debugger, and Windows App are not a hosting option for production environments anyway...

Comment: @Johann Blais - good point. I was still thinking about a problem where someone couldn't start their service.  Debugging the stop part should be no problem.